# Two's complement in C

Tags: c, math

Let's suppose a 16-bits variable (a) stored as unsigned 16-bits. If I cast to signed 16-bits can I say that I read my signed number (b) as two's complement format ?

```py
uint16_t a = 0xFFF1;
int16_t b;
b = (int16_t)a;
```

Comment: Not, you cannot, that's implementation dependent.  How do the unsigned numbers convert to signed and its relationship to two's complement is completely dependant of your hardware architecture.  You can have a computer that uses no two's complement signed numbers... so in case you have that, the details of the conversion will be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practically *yes*. All common architectures should be two's-complement and treat same-width unsigned-to-signed conversions as basically a no-op.

Theoretically *not always*. The C standard says that conversions to non-`_Bool` types do not change values if the values fit ([6.3.1.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p1)), otherwise for an unsigned-to-signed conversion you either get an implementation defined conversion or a signal is raised ([6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3)).

[6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3)

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.60)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
>   represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

(Conversions to _Bool are done by comparison to 0([6.3.1.2p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2p1)). There's also no change if the source fits (0 or 1), but all nonzero numbers convert to `(_Bool)1`, whereas if the wraparound rule ([6.3.1.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2)) applied, then even numbers would convert to `(_Bool)0`, but they don't.)

As [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) has noted in the comment, C2x should be removing the special case, and so the *practically yes* should become *always yes*.

Comment: Unless there'd be surprises, C2x will remove the other sign representations.

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm looking forward to that! I really like "Signed integers are two's complement" proposal. (I'm not too happy about  attributes, though (N2335). As proposed, I think they mess up the grammar by introducing a ton of shift-reduce conflicts. It could be done without those. Granted, then the thing wouldn't be C++ compatible, but I don't think C should care about that given that the languages have already diverged anyway.)

Comment: As your quoted text says _if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged_  (the value, not necessarily the representation)